# Currency Symbol Problem while using Laravel-Invoices Package

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, invoice, receipt

I'm using `laraveldaily/laravel-invoices` package to generate invoices. Here the problem is: I need BDT currency symbol "৳".

To do that, Here I'm using:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<span style="font-family: DejaVu Sans;">&#2547;</span>
```

**But, it's not working.** **How can I do this?**

Comment: Can you remove font family style in your span and try it? You can provide currency in your controller when using Laravel-invoices package.

Comment: It also not working. That's why I'm using that.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem when you try to export it to PDF. Can you try to use USD and $? If you have custom font it may not have this currency symbol.

Comment: USD symbol working well

Comment: Maybe your choosen font does not have this symbol, if you have any custom font please remove it then try it again.